# pre_get_posts with multiple post types AND a meta_key

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, pre-get-posts

So I am trying to customize the search a bit. The client wants the main site search to return people, projects, and posts. Not normally a problem. However for projects, only projects with a certain meta_key present are required.

```
function mta_search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
            $query->set('post_type', array('project', 'people', 'post'));
            $query->set('meta_key', 'list_only');
            $query->set('meta_value', '1');
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','mta_search_filter');
```

The above unfortunately will not return the people or posts because they will definitely not have the meta key. I know how to do this with get_posts or WP_Query but in this case I need to use pre_get_posts. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How would you do that with `WP_Query`? `pre_get_posts` operates on parameters of a `WP_Query` instance, so there's nothing you can do with `WP_Query` directly that you can't do via `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: I think, instead of settings meta_key and meta_value here you should enter the 'posts_where' and 'posts_join_paged' filter. add the postmeta-table yourself and add a where condition like ' ( ( wp_posts.post_type='project' && wp_post.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id && wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'list_only' && wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1' ) OR ( wp_posts.post_type != 'project' ) ) not tested though.

Comment: Milo what I meant was I can construct the correct results via multiple WP_Queries and array joining. But I want to be able to just augment the search using pre_get_posts.